# How to Sort String with Norwegian Characters in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, localization, locale, setlocale

æøå is the latest letters in the norwegian alphabet

```
   A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z Æ Ø Å

    List<String> words = Arrays.asList(
    "A", "B", "Z", "Æ", "Ø", "Å"     );

    Locale la = new Locale("nor", "NOR");
    Collator coll = Collator.getInstance(la);
    coll.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
    Collections.sort(words, coll);
    System.out.println(""+ words);
```

The answer should be

A, B, Z,  Æ, Ø Å,

But i am getting:

A, Å, Æ, B, Z, Ø

Can anyone suggest how to get above output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The locale was wrong. For norwegian, language is 'no' and Country is 'NO'

```
    List<String> words = Arrays.asList(
        "Abba", "B", "BØ", "BÆ", "Z", "Æ", "Ø", "Å"     );

    Locale la = new Locale("no", "NO");
    Collator coll = Collator.getInstance(la);
    coll.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
    Collections.sort(words, coll);
    System.out.println(""+ words);
```

Correct Output: [Abba, B, BÆ, BØ, Z, Æ, Ø, Å]

Comment: There's **NO** way you answered your own question that quick. ;)

Comment: I was doing work side wise and spent 30 minutes and was not getting correct. That was hit and tiral which worked at sudden after posting Question. So i thought of sharing. Nothing else

Comment: Interesting question&answer though, I'm glad you shared.